# Magento getIsAnchor() in template file

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I am trying to call `$this->getIsAnchor()` from a category template file to show certain information if the category has layered navigation.  The function is always returning false, even when it should be true.

Is there a problem with calling the function from a template file this way?  If so, what is the proper way to call this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make this call against the category instead:

```
$_category->getIsAnchor();
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may find using layout.xml a cleaner option.  There are different handles for layered and non layered categories:

**Non Layered Categroy Handle**

`<catalog_category_default>`

**Layered Category Handle**

`<catalog_category_layered>`

Comment: This worked after I added:
`$_category = $this->getCurrentCategory();`

Comment: That variable is already initialized for you at the top of category/view.phtml :)